# `new Object()' does not seem to create a new object, why?

Tags: java, object

I am having one of those weird moments.

```
ArrayList<Object> a = new ArrayList<Object>();
a.add(new Socket());
a.add(new Thread());
a.add("three");
a.add(a);
a.add(new Object());

for(Object output : a) {
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Output:

```
Socket[unconnected]
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
three
[Socket[unconnected], Thread[Thread-0,5,main], three, (this Collection)]
java.lang.Object@615e7597
```

Every time I run this, the new object always gives the same Hex String (Java doc `Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`), why is this? Why doesn't this produce a different String each time? Or is it reusing the same object because it can?

EDIT: I tried executing the Java application several times.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you running this in a loop, or are you executing the Java application several times?

Comment: I tried executing the Java application several times.

Comment: The JVM always starts from scratch, always go through the same steps until it creates your object, and you're thus seeing the same thing every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An object's hash code is typically calculated from its internal address (ref http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) so if you're re-running the program with an identical state, the address of the object in memory is likely to be the same each time.

It's not technically reusing the same object, because you're exiting the JVM; it's just following the same steps each time, creating an identical object in the same place in memory, which produces an identical hash code for toString() to return.

Answer (score 1):

New Object just happens to be created in the same memory location as before with few executions. It is expected to change. You might try executing the program 10 times, I feel atleast 2-3 times the object will be created in a different location.

This JVM behaviour cannot be claimed as wrong. It is wrong to even look into memory location in java and JVM has options to move the objects to different memory locations during the course of the execution.

Answer (score -1):

From the [Object.hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) documentation:

The general contract of hashCode is:

- Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
  execution 
      of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals
  comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain
  consistent from one execution of an application to another execution
  of the same application.
- If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must
  produce the same integer result.
- It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method
  on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hashtables.

Therefore it is valid that your Object has the same hashCode all the time.

Answer (score -1):

If `System.out.println` find Object reference than it always print `toString()` method. Here the `List` store differents Object reference with different `toString` implementations.

```
 ArrayList<Object> a = new ArrayList<Object>();
    a.add(new Socket());
```

For example, The `Socket` class `toString` is overrided as

```
public String toString() {
    try {
        if (isConnected())
            return "Socket[addr=" + getImpl().getInetAddress() +
                ",port=" + getImpl().getPort() +
                ",localport=" + getImpl().getLocalPort() + "]";
    } catch (SocketException e) {
    }
    return "Socket[unconnected]";
  }
```

So, you will see the output of `new Socket()` as `Socket[unconnected]`

Answer (score -1):

yeah,just like do this what you said.i tried to execute the Java application several times. the result the same as you said.but,the results just when we executed Java application.however,it's not same results when we **recompile** the Java application in eclipse. like this,you will get different hashcode values.Firstly,JVM will load the bytes file to memory when first **execute** java program.every time execute will get the same hashcode value ,just like "Rich Smith" replyed. every times will load the bytes file to memory when compiled program . so we will get different hashcode value and get different Object.